# alter a table column to nullable

Tags: mysql

I want to alter a field to nullable and add the default value null.table name 'other_details' column name used_asset which is varchar(100)

```
ALTER TABLE `other_details` ALTER COLUMN `used_asset` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
```

above query shows error 'syntax error near varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL'

Comment: You're missing a `NULL` statement before `DEFAULT NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This came from phpmyadmin as `preview SQL` and it seems to work:

```
ALTER TABLE `other_details` CHANGE `used_asset` `used_asset` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

1) Using **MODIFY**

```
ALTER TABLE `other_details` MODIFY `used_asset` varchar(100) null;
```

2) Using **CHANGE**

**Syntax**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name type DEFAULT NULL
```

**Example**

```
ALTER TABLE `other_details` CHANGE `used_asset` `used_asset` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name MODIFY Column_Name DataType DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.